# .Net Get recent opened item other App (Like in menu bar )

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows

its possible to get list recent item in windows like in this picture? how can i access that from vb.net?

list recent item(right click on icon bar)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnPtQ.png

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is a Jump List. You can access from within .NET starting with .NET 4. Since you want this in VB.Net check out this [article](https://donatstudios.com/WPF-VBNet-JumpList-Example)
and the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.jumplist(v=vs.110).aspx) on msdn

```
Imports System.Windows.Shell
Class Application

    Public Sub New()

        Dim jl As New JumpList
        JumpList.SetJumpList(Application.Current, jl)

        Dim SaveAs As New JumpTask
        SaveAs.ApplicationPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.Location()
        SaveAs.Title = "Save as..."
        SaveAs.Arguments = "-saveas"
        jl.JumpItems.Add(SaveAs)

        Dim Configuration As New JumpTask
        Configuration.ApplicationPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.Location()
        Configuration.Title = "Configuration"
        Configuration.CustomCategory = "Settings"
        Configuration.Arguments = "-config"
        jl.JumpItems.Add(Configuration)

        jl.Apply()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Application_Startup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup

        ' Handle "Save As" JumpList example
        If e.Args.Contains("-saveas") Then
            ' Fancy Code Funtime
            ' -- Remember, this launches as a new instance - if you don't want that, this end kills it when your done --
            End
        End If

        ' Handle "Configuration" JumpList example
        If e.Args.Contains("-config") Then
            ' I launch a configuration window here, really up to you
            ' -- Remember, this launches as a new instance - if you don't want that, this end kills it when your done --
            End
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```